# check local network permission in react-native

Tags: react-native, local-network

I want to redirect users to the setting screen if they don't allow local network permission.

But not able to find any solution of the function which gets data about the allowed and disallowed status of local network permission.

I have tried a `react-native-local-network-permission` library but it's also getting error as below

**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNLocalNetworkPermission.check')**

Let me know if we have any support for this issue or if we can detect the status of local network permission.

Comment: Is this Expo app or React-Native-Cli also my guess is any check on network will be async, so be sure to await the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither React Native Autolinking or running `npx react-native link react-native-local-network-permission` works for this package. You have to follow the manual linking instructions.

- follow the manual linking instructions from: https://github.com/navico-mobile/react-native-local-network-permission/blob/main/README.md#user-content-manual-installation

> Manual installation - iOS
>
> In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]
>
> Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-local-network-permission and add RNLocalNetworkPermission.xcodeproj
>
> In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNLocalNetworkPermission.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries

- Then fix the search paths: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/461#issuecomment-553355501

> Go to Project navigator > Libraries > [library name here].xcodeproj
>
> Click on Build Settings and then the first item under "Targets"
>
> Scroll down to 'Search Paths'
>
> Double click to edit the 'Header Search Paths'
>
> Add the following entry (click '+'): ${SRCROOT}/../../../ios/Pods/Headers.
>
> Make sure to set it to recursive.
>
> Clean (cmd + shift + K) and re-build (cmd + B)